# find the geometric set of points, planes, and lines.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

can you check my work whether it is correct or not.

question : Describe geometrically the following sets as points, lines, planes, or all of $\Bbb R^n$.

$a) \ \{(x,y) : 2x+3y = 1, -x+y = 3\}$

$b) \ \operatorname{span}\{(1,1,2), (0,1,-1), (-1,0,2)\}$

Attempt :
$a)$ the geometric description of the set is a point of coordinate $(-5/4, 7/6)$.
$b)$ the set of vectors is linearly independent, therefore the geometric description is a plane.

how do i write the equation of the plane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

y=7/5, x=-8/5 is the solution of the first system of equations. For the second, if vectors are independent, they span $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: how do i write the equations of the plane?

Comment: The equation of a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ is $ax+by+cz+d=0$. For your case, the plane must go through the origin, so $d=0$

Comment: a, b, c will be found by cross product? if yes, i have 3 vectors how do i do that

Comment: No. Just plug in some values. Suppose you want to calculate the span of the first two vectors. $a1+b1+c2=0$ and $a0+b1-c1=0$. The system is not fully determined. You can choose any $b$, say $b=1$. Then $c=1$ and $a=-3$. The equation of the plane is $-3x+y+z=0$

Comment: ohhh. i see, thanks for the explantion.